# Trouble connecting angular frontEnd with javaBackend?

Tags: java, angular, typescript, cors

I am trying to call the API in Backend but I have some error that I have not an idea from what is causing by.
The problem started after I config the spring security in the backend.
The call should activate  Preflighted requests OPTION
In my backend file, I have

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SpringSecurityConfigurationBasicAuth extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {    
            http.csrf().disable();
            http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS,"/**").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                    .and()
//            .formLogin().and()
                .httpBasic();
    }
}
```

and in the frontend, I have this part of the code.

```
  executeHelloWorldServiceWithPathVariable(name) {
    const basicAuthHeaderString = this.createBasicAuthenticationHttpHeader();

    const headers = new HttpHeaders({
        Authorization: basicAuthHeaderString
      });
    return this.http.get<HelloWorldBean>(`http://localhost:8080/hello-world/path-variable/${name}`,
      {headers});
  }

  createBasicAuthenticationHttpHeader() {
    const username = 'start';
    const password = 'end';
    const basicAuthHeaderString = 'Basic ' + window.btoa(username + ':' + password);
    return basicAuthHeaderString;
  }
```

In the backend, I have already include

> @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")

but still, I am not able to call this API
in the console, I should get something like an OPTION method but in fact, I get those:

> General

```
Request URL: http://localhost:8080/hello-world/path-variable/start
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

> Response Header

```
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 0
Date: Tue, 28 Jan 2020 11:11:49 GMT
Expires: 0
Keep-Alive: timeout=60
Pragma: no-cache
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Realm"
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Realm"
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
```

> request head

Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
    Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
    Accept-Language: en,cs;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8
    Authorization: Basicc3RhcnQ6ZWVuZA==
    Connection: keep-alive
    Host: localhost:8080
    Origin: http://localhost:4200
    Referer: http://localhost:4200/welcome/start
    Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
    Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site
    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36

and in console, I see this error 
[image: error console]

Answer (score 0):

Try to add cors policy in your security configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SpringSecurityConfigurationBasicAuth extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {    
            http.csrf().disable();
            http.cors();
            http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS,"/**").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                    .and()
//            .formLogin().and()
                .httpBasic();
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok so the main error with Cors is gone but now I am having 401 for the API that I am trying to call any other suggestion

Comment: That is probalby because you permit only `OPTIONS` request, so all other are unauthorized. It is in this line: `http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS,"/**").permitAll()`

Comment: I don't think the problem is there, as even if i change this to Http.method.GET still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

to the class `SpringSecurityConfigurationBasicAuth` try to add this method

```
@Bean
  CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
      CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
      configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("http://localhost:4200"));
      configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET","POST"));
      UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
      source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
      return source;
  }
```